# If $G = R \rtimes G_{\alpha}$ and $R$ is non-abelian of order $27$ and exponent $3$, then $G_{\alpha} \ncong D_{12}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions, semidirect-product

Suppose that $G = R \rtimes G_{\alpha}$ is a finite permutation group on $\Omega$ where $R$ is the non-abelian subgroup of order $27$ and exponent $3$ (see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_27)). Suppose that $G_{\alpha} \cong D_n$, where $D_n$ denotes the dihedral group of order $2n$ (considering $C_2\times C_2$ as dihedral). Now look at the orbits of $G_{\alpha}$, and suppose we have the orbit $\{\alpha\}$ and three other orbits where $G_{\alpha}$ acts non-regular, one of size $2$ and two of size $n$, the other orbits being regular for $G_{\alpha}$.

Now as $|\Omega| = |R| = 27$ this gives that
$$
 27 = 1 + 2 + n + n + 2nk
$$
for some $k$ by an orbit decomposition. So we have $n \in \{2,3,4,6,12\}$. Now I want to rule out the case $n = 12$. But I have no idea.

> So why is $n = 12$ not possible?

This must have something to do with the orbit decomposition above. Some further facts: We have $Z(R) = \Phi(R)$ has order $3$ and $Z(R)$ is normal in $G$ and partitions $\Omega$ into orbits of size $3$ that are blocks under $G$.

Remark: The action of $G_{\alpha}$ on $\Omega$ is equivalent to the action of $G_{\alpha}$ on $R$. So we could as well dispose the set $\Omega$ and just consider a semidirect product $R \rtimes H$ where $H$ acts on $R$.

Comment: The header of your question is a little odd, or I am missing something basic here: if $\;|R|=27\;$ then $\;|G|= |R\rtimes G_\alpha|\ge 27\;$ ,so how could if be possible $\;G\;$ is isomorphic with the dihedral group of order $\;24\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo Thanks for pointing out! I meant the stabilizer (or the group that acts on $R$ in the semidirect product) not the whole group. In the question itself its written correctly.

Comment: The automorphism group of $R$ is isomorphic to ${\rm AGL}(2,3)$ (which is the semidirect product of an elementary abelian group of order $9$ with its automorphism group ${\rm GL}(2,3)$), and ${\rm AGL}(2,3)$ has no element of order $12$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see the cyclic subgroup of $G_{\alpha}$ would then be a cyclic subgroup of this automorphism group, which is not possible. Thanks!